# Error in my stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic

I try to write stored procedure which will check:

1. If table and columns exists then we write data
2. If table not exist then we create it and write data
3. If table exist then we check existing columns and we write data into exists
   columns

This is the code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[my_proc] @file_path VARCHAR(1000) = NULL
    ,@file_type VARCHAR(1000) = NULL
    ,@file_name VARCHAR(1000) = NULL
    ,@table_name VARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000);

    SET @table_name = '[dbo].[' + @table_name + ']'
    SET @sql = '
    DECLARE @msg VARCHAR(max)

    --if column and table exist
    IF (
            EXISTS (
                SELECT *
                FROM sys.objects
                WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(''' + @table_name + ''', ''U'')
                ) --табличка
            AND EXISTS (
                SELECT *
                FROM sys.columns
                WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(''' + @table_name + ''', ''U'')
                    AND (
                        NAME = '' path_file ''
                        AND NAME = '' file_type ''
                        AND NAME = '' file_name ''
                        )
                )
            ) --поля
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO ' + @table_name + ' (
            file_path
            ,file_type
            ,file_name
            )
        VALUES (
            ''' + isnull(@file_path, '') + '''
            ,''' + isnull(@file_type, '') + '''
            ,''' + isnull(@f ile_name, '') + '''
            )
    END

    --if table not exist
    IF NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM sys.objects
            WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(''' + @table_name + ''', ''U'')
            )
    BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE ' + @table_name + ' (
            id INT NOT NULL identity(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY
            ,file_path TEXT
            ,file_name TEXT
            ,file_type TEXT
            )
    END

    --if table exist
    IF EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM sys.objects
            WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(''' + @table_name + ''', ''U'')
            )
    BEGIN
        --check for columns in table
        --file_path
        IF NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT *
                FROM sys.columns
                WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(''' + @table_name + ''', ''U'')
                    AND (
                        NAME = ''path_file''
                        OR NAME = ''file_path''
                        )
                )
        BEGIN
            PRINT (''NOT COLUMN path_file'')
        END

        --file name
        IF NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT *
                FROM sys.columns
                WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(''' + @table_name + ''', '' U '')
                    AND NAME = '' file_name ''
                )
        BEGIN
            PRINT ('' NOT COLUMN file_name '')
        END

        --file_type
        IF NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT *
                FROM sys.columns
                WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(''' + @table_name + ''', ''U'')
                    AND (
                        NAME = ''file_type''
                        OR NAME = ''file_type''
                        )
                )
        BEGIN
            PRINT (''NOT COLUMN file_type'')
        END
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO ' + @table_name + ' (
                file_path
                ,file_name
                ,file_type
                )
            VALUES (
                ''' + isnull(@file_path, '') + '''
                ,''' + isnull(@file_name, '') + '''
                ,''' + isnull(@f ile_type, '') + '''
                )
    END';

    EXEC (@sql);
END
```

Trouble with already existing table, but without columns I need

Help me please

Comment: Can you post the exact query that is being executed? You can get that by putting `print @sql` before the last line. So when you execute the SP in SSMS, it will print the query. Also, notice that your procedure is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Before anything, address that injection issue. Parametrise your SQL and quote your object names. Also don't use a `varchar(1000)` for `@table_name`. The definition of an object's name is a `nvarchar(128)` (or `sysname`). Using a 1000 gives you an huge over exposure for injection, especially when 872 of those characters could never be used for a valid object name.

Comment: This is an unusual way to handle data insert in DB. It looks like XY problem (http://xyproblem.info/). Could you please share what the issue you are trying to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run your script and the only error was happening was a miss declared variable.

You were writing "@f ile_name" with an empty space.

BTW I would suggest you to split your code to read. I tried to mess as little as possible.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[my_proc] 
    @file_path VARCHAR(1000) = NULL
    ,@file_type VARCHAR(1000) = NULL
    ,@file_name VARCHAR(1000) = NULL
    ,@table_name VARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000);
    DECLARE @msg VARCHAR(max);

    SET @table_name = '[dbo].[' + @table_name + ']'
    SET @sql = '
    --If table not exist then we create it
    IF NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM sys.objects
            WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''' + @table_name + ''')
                AND type IN (N''U'')
            )
    BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE ' + @table_name + ' (
            id INT NOT NULL identity(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY
            ,file_path TEXT
            ,file_name TEXT
            ,file_type TEXT
            )
    END';

    EXEC (@sql);

    SET @sql = '
    --If table exist then we check existing columns and we write data into exists columns
    IF EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM sys.objects
            WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(''' + @table_name + ''', ''U'')
            )
    BEGIN
        PRINT (''TABLE found'')

        --check for columns in table
        --file_path
        IF NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT *
                FROM sys.columns
                WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(''' + @table_name + ''', '' U '')
                    AND (
                        NAME = '' path_file ''
                        OR NAME = ''file_path''
                        )
                )
        BEGIN
            PRINT (''NOT COLUMN path_file'')
        END

        --file name
        IF NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT *
                FROM sys.columns
                WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(''' + @table_name + ''', ''U'')
                    AND NAME = ''file_name''
                )
        BEGIN
            PRINT (''NOT COLUMN file_name'')
        END

        --file_type
        IF NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT *
                FROM sys.columns
                WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(''' + @table_name + ''', ''U'')
                    AND (
                        NAME = ''file_type''
                        OR NAME = ''file_type''
                        )
                )
        BEGIN
            PRINT (''NOT COLUMN file_type'')
        END
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO ' + @table_name + ' (
                file_path
                ,file_name
                ,file_type
                )
            VALUES (
                ''' + isnull(@file_path, '') + '''
                ,''' + isnull(@file_name, '') + '''
                ,''' + isnull(@file_type, '') + '''
                )
    END';

    EXEC (@sql);

    SET @sql = '
    --If table and columns exists then we write data
    IF (
            EXISTS (
                SELECT *
                FROM sys.objects
                WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(''' + @table_name + ''', ''U'')
                ) --табличка
            AND EXISTS (
                SELECT *
                FROM sys.columns
                WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(''' + @table_name + ''', ''U'')
                    AND (
                        NAME = ''path_file''
                        AND NAME = ''file_type''
                        AND NAME = ''file_name''
                        )
                )
            ) --поля
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO ' + @table_name + ' (
            file_path
            ,file_type
            ,file_name
            )
        VALUES (
            ''' + isnull(@file_path, '') + '''
            ,''' + isnull(@file_type, '') + '''
            ,''' + isnull(@file_name, '') + '''
            )
    END';

    EXEC (@sql);
END
```